# Err 80 appearsCanon EOS 5D Mark II

Tags: canon

I tried using the solution u've said, switch off removing battery & cf card & switch it on, holding the shutter button for 30 seconds but has failed work for me.Kabirisi Mugyenyi Muganga in Uganda East Africa.

Comment: Then you probably need to send it in for repair.